# send_reset_password_instructions not changing token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

`u.send_reset_password_instructions` sends a url to

`/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=zybhayhwh` (edited for SO)

but this token is always the same, no matter how many times I reset my password or call u.send_reset_password_instructions

Incidentally, when I'm taken to the reset page I get redirected to the home page immediately.. probably because the cookie has the old token.

Why is my token not changing?

Comment: Plase, open your `rails console` and run this code twice: `User.first. send_reset_password_instructions` and check the returned values of the method call

Comment: The results are different when I run u.send_reset_password_instructions twice.

Comment: Look at the source or `send_reset_password_instructions`:  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib%2Fdevise%2Fmodels%2Frecoverable.rb#L54. The problem shouldn't be in devise, but in your email sender code. Looks that the email is always the same

Comment: I'm not modifying the email sender code. I'm just calling devise's methods.